# Why should one learn register level programing for embedded systems, when options like Arduino IDE ,etc are available?

Tags: embedded, arduino-ide

I have done projects using Arduino IDE.I have seen that many projects can be easily implemented using the IDE.Then, why should one learn register level programing? How important is it?

Comment: I'm okay with other people not learning it. I like the advantage afforded by understanding the underlying architecture.

Comment: Do you think it's useless to learn any math since calculators exist?

Answer (score 4):

Can you do *EVERYTHING* with the Arduino library? If your project would need tight timing (for example to control a huge industrial apparatus), at the level of microsecond fractions, would Arduino still be a good choice? How about medical devices? How about performance - would you be able to design a BLDC controller using Vector Control in Arduino? How about battery life - would you be able to design a device that would run with a single CR2032 cell for a few years using Arduino? How about doing a network router? Does Arduino support threads?

Your question is like one of these:

- who needs x-bit microcontrollers when we have y-bit microcontrollers at the same price?
- who needs x programming language when we have y programming language?
- who needs analog solutions when we have digital solutions?
- who needs microcontrollers when we have microprocessors?
- ...

To be honest, personally (I write firmware for embedded devices),I see Arduino as a toy, nothing more.

Comment: I work with embedded systems and can attest to not being fond of Arduino.  Any mention of a student at a university using it is guaranteed to make me nauseous.  Relying on libraries to perform everything is a sure way to code bloat and extremely difficult debugging issues.

Answer (score 2):

Learning register level programming will help you learning how to read a datasheet, and also understanding how stuff works. It will give you more flexibility after you get the hang of it, plus you can optimize your code and write your own libraries.

By knowing how to read a datasheet it will be easier for you to develop device drivers and process algorithms.

What would you do if you cannot find an Arduino library for a certain sensor? If you were using register level programming, you could easily write your driver, by already knowing how to interpret the technical files ;).

Try it out, you will forget Arduino in the first weeks!

Best regards,
Alex Tofan